# Efficiently query nodes and edges using SQL

Tags: sql-server, nodes, edges

I have 2 SQL Server tables that store network information, the EF schemas are:

```
public partial class edge
{
    public long edge_id { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public string target { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> edgedate { get; set; }
}

public partial class node
{
    public string node_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}
```

I am passing edge and node specific filters from the UI to be built into SQL queries like this:

```
select * 
from [dbo].[Nodes] 
where name = 'John Doe' 
   or address = '123 Fake Street'  

select * 
from [dbo].[Edges] 
where edgedate >= '01/12/2020 00:00:00' 
  and edgedate <= '01/12/2021 23:59:59
```

However these queries have to account for the **entire** network, i.e. node filters have to be applied to edges and vice versa -

```
-- nodes example with edge filters applied
select * 
from [dbo].[Nodes] 
where name = 'John Doe' 
   or address = '123 Fake Street'  
   and node_id in (select source 
                   from EDGESTEMP 
                   where edgedate >= '01/12/2020 00:00:00' 
                     and edgedate <= '01/12/2021 23:59:59'
                   union 
                   select target 
                   from EDGESTEMP 
                   where edgedate >= '01/12/2020 00:00:00' 
                     and edgedate <= '01/12/2021 23:59:59')
```

This works fine on small scale networks, however if I am dealing with networks of say a million edges and 500k nodes the performance to run these queries takes a hit, because of the **in** statements when checking the other table in each instance.

I have added indexes on all the affiliated columns for the queries however need to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this?

**Additional Info**

Query plan - [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByBp5daHK)

Clustered indexes are set on each primary key i.e. node_id and edge_id and non clustered set on the rest e.g. -

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-20211017-194859] ON [dbo].[NODES]
(
    [name] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Please show your indexes. Please also share a query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: Why are both "source" and "target" defined as string in the edge class? Shouldn't they be of type long, since you are using them as a foreign key for the nodes ID?

Comment: Side point: Looks like you're missing brackets around that `or` clause

Comment: @RandomUser correct that was an editing mistake you are absolutely correct. Ill get the query plan.

Comment: @Ebikeneser I don't think there is a more efficient way of doing it in SQL, i would just point out this feature https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-sample?view=sql-server-ver15 . hope it helps

Comment: @Charlieface have added what you requested, currently just for nodes.

Comment: There is no need for a union and datetime range query is faulty (which may cause wrong results regardless of performance). Date literals are ambiguous. Take care of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your query appears to have a logic error: there should be parenthesis around the `or`.

Secondly, `UNION ALL` is usually better than `UNION`, although it often doesn't matter in a semi-join such as `IN` or `EXISTS`

```sql
select n.* 
from [dbo].[Nodes] n
where (n.name = 'John Doe' 
       or n.address = '123 Fake Street')
 and node_id in (
    select source
    from EDGES 
    where edgedate >= '01/12/2020 00:00:00' 
      and edgedate <= '01/12/2021 23:59:59'
    union all
    select target 
    from EDGES
    where edgedate >= '01/12/2020 00:00:00' 
      and edgedate <= '01/12/2021 23:59:59'
);
```

Finally, for this query, you should probably have the following indexes

```
NODES (name) INCLUDE (node_id)

NODES (address) INCLUDE (node_id)

EDGES (edgedate) INCLUDE (source, target)
```

The `or` condition may still cause issues, as you may still get an index scan on `NODES`. If so, you may need to rewrite the query to force an index union instead.

```sql
select n.* 
from (
    select *
      from [dbo].[Nodes] n
      where n.name = 'John Doe'
    union
    select *
      from [dbo].[Nodes] n
      where n.address = '123 Fake Street'
) n
where node_id in (
    select source
    from EDGES 
    where edgedate >= '01/12/2020 00:00:00' 
      and edgedate <= '01/12/2021 23:59:59'
    union all
    select target 
    from EDGES
    where edgedate >= '01/12/2020 00:00:00' 
      and edgedate <= '01/12/2021 23:59:59'
);
```

Comment: I shall attempt this and get back to you! Are the current indexes perhaps the main reason this is not as performant at bigger volumes?

Comment: I deleted all my previous indexes, they were missing the includes you mentioned, and also tweaked the query as suggested and it cut 7 seconds of my query execution time. Well done.

Comment: Please share the new query plan

Answer (score 1):

You can use exists for a more efficient query instead of that union.

Also, you shouldn't use ambiguous date literals. I was not sure if those dates were Jan 12 or Dec 1. Plus, for datetime range queries, you shouldn't use >= and <= but >= and <. You can see these adjusments in code:

```
select * 
from [dbo].[Nodes] n
where (name = 'John Doe' 
   or address = '123 Fake Street')  
   and exists (select * 
               from EDGESTEMP e
                   where (n.node_id = e.source or n.node_id = e.target)
                         and e.edgedate >= '20200112' 
                         and e.edgedate < '20210113');
```

BTW, I assume you already have indexes on source, target and edgedate. If not create them.

Comment: @Ebikeneser, BTW, your clustered indexes also would play a role in this query. There is no way to know your general usage of your tables, but if it is generally like this one, it looks like you might want to explicitly set a clustered index on edgedate (including source and target may add value). By default, SQL server creates the clustered index on primary key, here your edge_id which doesn't have any role in this query (and likely nowhere else too).